# May I omit every semicolon at the end of line in all version (if any) of JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I'm learning JavaScript and I somehow figured out that I may skip typing `;` at the end of a line, as long as there's only one statement in that line. In fact I'm used to this a bit; I developed a simple iOS app with Swift which supports this kind of syntax too.

But what I'm wondering is whether there's a specific version or something of JavaScript which does not allow programmers to omit the last semicolon. Lots of languages have had changes in syntax; so I guess JavaScript might have this kind of problem.

Comment: JavaScript will put the semicolons for you according to the rules of Automatic Semicolon Insertion (ASI)

Comment: And afaik that's "always" been the case.

Comment: For better or for worse, it's part of the language and isn't likely to go away.  It would be nice to have a way to opt out (similar to strict mode) but as it stands every standards-compliant interpreter must support it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that while all versions of JavaScript support ASI, there are pitfalls of ASI that will mean you can't get rid of **all** semicolons.

For example, the following will not work as you might expect:

```
function foo() { return [2, 3] }

var x, y, i, j
j = 2
i = j
[x,y] = foo()
```

You might expect that `i`, `j`, and `x` will equal 2, and `y` will equal 3, which is what would happen if every line were semicolon-terminated.  However, that is not the case.

In fact, `i` is `[2,3]`, while `x` and `y` are `undefined`.  When ASI ran on that section of code, it interpreted the final two lines as a property access:

```
i = j[x,y] = foo()
```

while it was probably intended to be a destructuring operation:

```
i = j;
[x,y] = foo();
```

A method to get around this is to use "defensive semicolons" before any line beginning with [] or () that is not intended to be treated as the continuation of the previous statement.